# how to get mutliple row data of same name in one row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, union

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT 'Rupesh' Name ,'2014-02-27 00:00:00.000' OfficeDate,'9.30' InTime,'' OutTime
UNION
SELECT 'Rupesh' Name,'2014-02-27 00:00:00.000' OfficeDate,'' InTime,'6.30' OutTime
UNION
SELECT 'Rupesh' Name ,'2014-02-26 00:00:00.000' OfficeDate,'11.30' InTime,'' OutTime
UNION
SELECT 'Rupesh' Name ,'2014-02-26 00:00:00.000' OfficeDate,'' InTime,'9.30' OutTime
)p
```

Sample-data:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Name    |OfficeDate                 |InTime|OutTime
----------------------------------------------------
Rupesh  |   2014-02-26 00:00:00.000 |       |9.30
Rupesh  |   2014-02-26 00:00:00.000 |11.30  |   
Rupesh  |   2014-02-27 00:00:00.000 |       |6.30
Rupesh  |   2014-02-27 00:00:00.000 |9.30   |   
----------------------------------------------------
```

What i want result is in following way:

```
Rupesh  2014-02-26 00:00:00.000 11.30   9.30    

Rupesh  2014-02-27 00:00:00.000 9.30    6.30
```

Comment: is it possible you can have multiple In and out time for a single day?

Comment: I am still wondering about table definition and data in IN Time and OUT time columns will be in 12 hrs or 24 hours format?

Comment: please provide the details correctly and completely, so that the answer given is correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks You guyz, but i solved it by self here's the solution:

```
SELECT name, OfficeDate, [InTime] ,[OutTime] from 
 (
    SELECT name,OfficeDate, 'OutTime' status,OutTime Times from #DATA           
    UNION           
    SELECT name,OfficeDate, 'InTime' status, InTime Times from #DATA    
 ) x
pivot 
(
   MAX(Times)
   for status in (InTime,OutTime)
) p
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to group by `Name`, `OfficeDate` and merge `InTime` and `OutTime`?
You could use following CTE which uses [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT Name, OfficeDate, 
         InTimeOld = InTime, OutTimeOld = OutTime,
         InTimeNew = MAX(InTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Name, OfficeDate), 
         OutTimeNew= MAX(OutTime)OVER(PARTITION BY Name, OfficeDate),
         RN = Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name, OfficeDate
                                 Order By Name, OfficeDate, Intime, OutTime)
  FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT Name, OfficeDate, InTime = InTimeNew, OutTime = OutTimeNew
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ace0c/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE1.Name,
    TABLE1.OfficeDate,
    MAX(TABLE1.InTime) AS InTime,
    MAX(TABLE1.OutTime) AS OutTime
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY
    TABLE1.Name,
    TABLE1.OfficeDate
```

Comment: Hey, I dont think the time should be hardcoded in the query.. It should by dynamic from the column, as expected by the user...

Comment: @Murtaza : I thought that the first select is a generation of the sample data. If you look at the sample data that the OP have and the result.

Comment: Intime should be `MIN(TABLE1.InTime)`, Employees will run away if you will count max in time in your organization ;)

Comment: @Murtaza : No. because then it will pick the empty InTime

Comment: i do not agree on your solution, suppose it about counting employees in and out time in company, he can go out and come in several times, but the first in time and last out time should be calculated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57912/discussion-between-murtaza-and-arion).

Answer (score -1):

Refer [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e924/2):

```
SELECT 
    TABLE1.Name,
    TABLE1.OfficeDate,
    MIN(TABLE1.InTime) AS InTime,   -- Minimum Intime
    MAX(TABLE1.OutTime) AS OutTime   --- Maximum Outtime
FROM TableName TABLE1
GROUP BY
    TABLE1.Name,
    TABLE1.OfficeDate;
```

Comment: what if Intime and outtime is not decimal type ?

Comment: @Murtaza: I am refering to the sample input provided by the OP. The query gives the output required